# Необычное разбиение строки

Tags: c++, visual-studio, парсер, strtok

Имеется программа для разбиения строки по регулярному выражению (парсинг). Программа читает строку из файла, разбивает по ";", вписывает в вектор типа структура и выводит на экран. Проблема в том, что программа почему-то дважды записывает одно и то же. Как я могу решить свою проблему?
Спасибо.
Код и скрины прилагаются.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <io.h>


using namespace std;

struct pointXY
{
    char *x;
    char *y;
};

pointXY *dot;

int main()
{
    dot = new pointXY;
    FILE *file;
    fopen_s(&file, "poly.txt", "r");
    if (file!=NULL)
    {
        int count = 0;
        long sz;
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        sz = ftell(file)+1;
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
        char *read, *pars;
        read = new char[sz];
        fgets(read, sz, file);
        pars = strtok(read, ";");
        vector<pointXY> pole;
        while (pars != NULL)
        {
            if (count % 2 == 0)
            {
                dot->x = pars;
                pole.push_back(*dot);
            }
            else
            {
                dot->y = pars;
                pole.push_back(*dot);
            }
            pars = strtok(NULL, ";");
            count++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < count/2; i++)
        {
            cout << pole[i].x << " -- " << pole[i+1].y << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Open Error";
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое `#include <io.h>` и к чему оно тут?

Comment: Пытался размер файла узнать и какая-то функция требовала этой библиотеки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать проще. Например:

```
using namespace std;
ifstream file("poly.txt");
vector<string> vs;
string s;
while   (getline(file, s, ';'))
    vs.push_back(s);

for (int i = 1; i < vs.size(); i += 2)
    cout << vs[i - 1] << " -- " << vs[i] << endl;
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, но мой вектор должен хранить структуру, а не строку.

Comment: Ну передайте строки из вектора в  структуры. Хотя не понятно  для чего вам эта структура...

Comment: Сделал все, как вы сказали - все получилось!
Спасибо большое! Код стал в 4 раза меньше:)

Answer (score 2):

Ваш странный цикл чтения создает в памяти вектор таких пар

```
{ 0, мусор }
{ 0, 1 }    
{ 2, 1 }
{ 2, 3 }
{ 4, 3 }
{ 4, 5 }
{ 6, 5 }
{ 6, 7 }
{ 8, 7 }
{ 8, 9 }
```

После чего вы выводите первые пять по [странному] диагональному правилу `pole[i].x -- pole[i+1].y`. (Видимо странность вывода должна компенсировать странность чтения.)

Получается то, что получается. Что написали, то и получили.

Зачем понадобился такой странный цикл чтения и странный вектор в результате - не ясно. Но чтобы из него "выцарапать" пары исходных "координат" вашим странным способом вывода (т.е. для того, чтобы странность вывода действительно скомпенсировала странность чтения), вам придется выводить данные с шагом `i += 2`, а не `i++`. И не до `i < count / 2`, а до `i < count`.

Но я бы предположил, с точки зрения здравого смысла, что исходный замысел все таки состоял в формировании вектора

```
{ 0, 1 }    
{ 2, 3 }
{ 4, 5 }
{ 6, 7 }
{ 8, 9 }
```

при чтении. А для этого надо переделывать *все*.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!
Помогло: вам придется выводить данные с шагом i += 2, а не i++. И не до i < count / 2, а до i < count.
Исходный замысел выглядит именно так, как вы предположили:)